# css - make the transition works just for one way

Tags: css

I have the following code in css:

```
.item {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
}

.item.seen {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

when I add the class `seen` to an `.item`, the `opacity` of the item turn from 0 to 1 with transition.

but when I remove the class `seen` from an `.item` the `opacity` transition (from 1 to 0) also runs.

is there any way to make the transition run when `.seen` is added but not when it is removed?

Answer (score 5):

```
.item {
    opacity: 0;
}

.item.seen {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qcxt3evn/ (with `opacity` set to `0.2` just for the purpose of seeing the clickable element)

Also, don't forget to place the standard property *after* the vendor-prefixed (the latter might be non-compliant to the specification)

Comment: This is the opposite of what was asked for.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, the `class` which contains the `transition` never change.

If you setup your `transition` in the `class` which toggle, the transition won't be effective on the *remove*.

```
.item {
    opacity: 0;
}

.item.seen {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s linear;
    transition: opacity 1s linear;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RedBreast/ku784868/1/)**

---

**To go beyond**, as also well explained in the article [Ordering CSS3 Properties](https://css-tricks.com/ordering-css3-properties/) from *Chris Coyier*, you should be careful about the **order** of you prefixes, with the very good example attached to the article:

http://codepen.io/css-tricks/pen/pqgKH

```
#wrongway { background: #ccc; padding: 30px; 
  border-radius: 30px 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px 10px;
}
#rightway { background: #ccc; padding: 30px; 
  -webkit-border-radius: 30px 10px;
  border-radius: 30px 10px;
}
```